# How can I lock my android app into portrait / landscape mode programatically?

Tags: java, android, landscape, portrait

I came up with a problem right now when my game is almost finish. The problem is that I want the player to be able to play both in landscape mode and portrait. How the player change mode is simple. Before he start the game, a message comes up and lets him decide witch mode he wants to play. Here comes the problem. In the Manifest.xml file - you can tell the game to play on just portrait or just landscape mode. So I wanna use a boolean to show witch one of the modes the player chose. But in xml, there is no "if" that can change the game depence the players choise. So how do I do to change the mode to the that one that the player choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`context.setRequestedOrientation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29) and place your xml inside the `layout-land` or `layout-port` folder.

Android will automatically choose the right layout depending on parameter `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` or `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT`

Comment: I don't want the user to change the screen orientation right in the missle of game, just before and in the options menu.